# Ritual Casting for E6 Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, e6

I'm GMing an E6 campaign using the Pathfinder system. I want to include ritual casting system, to allow for higher power effects such as teleportation, planar crossing, resurrection, divinations, etc. as well as lower level hedge mage rituals (protection against evil, find north, etc).

However, I've been unable to find a system that I feel both works well for low levels and allows me to convert existing spells into rituals.

I'm thinking about converting the 4th ed ritual casting system into something I could use, but I figured that I'd ask here, if anyone knows of any good ritual casting systems, useful in my situation.

Comment: Check out 5e, they use 3e style spellcasting but also have ritual casting. You might get some inspiration there.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [3.5 Unearthed Arcana's ritual spellcasting](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/magic/incantations.htm). It works marvelously under E6, since the skill bonuses don't yet reach overpowering levels and the 30-ish difficulties are yet near-epic.

One of the example incantations there is the plane shift to a predefined plane. It has a casting time of 60 minutes and requires six successful DC 20 checks of two different skills and four additional casters. That is quite E6-manageable trade of quantity to quality.

Comment: I looked at Unearthed Arcana, but I seem to remember that I found the guidelines for creating new rituals useless for my use. Might be a personal taste issue, though. Can't remember what the exact problem was, but too high DCs were a part of it. Might also be that I found the use of multiple successive skill rolls rather than a single roll to be a bad design choice.

Comment: @Rubberduck take a look again and if you still have the problem, tell us what it is.